# Django: How can i do annotate just when all my models have some value

Tags: django, django-views

Let me explain better... i have this models:

```
class BetGroup(models.Model):
  ...
  expected_value = models.DecimalField(_('Expected Value')...
  code = models.CharField(_('Code'), max_length=126, blank=True, null=True)
  ...

class Bet(models.Model):
  ...
  bet_group = models.ForeignKey(
    BetGroup, verbose_name=_('Bet group'),
    related_name='bet', on_delete=models.CASCADE
  )
  is_correct = models.NullBooleanField(_('Is correct?'), default=None)
  ...
```

i want to make a query when all bets in bet_group is correct sum expected_value.

i want to test if all bets are correct then sum expected_value for each bet_group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to do something [like this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships):

```
BetGroup.objects.exclude(bet__is_correct=False)
```

to get the BetGroups where all the bets are correct and then perform the [aggregate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/)/annotate over the `expected_value`, for example:

```
from django.db.models import Sum 
BetGroup.objects.exclude(bet__is_correct=False).aggregate(sum_expected_value=Sum('expected_value')).get('sum_expected_value')
```

Comment: But it's not like this, because i just want sum expected value if all bets on betgroup is correct().

Comment: The `BetGroup.objects.exclude(bet__is_correct=False)` will exclude all the BetGroup objects where at least one bet isn't correct, if I'm not mistaken. Isn't that what you want?